# Kendo UI Angular2 - How to implement drag and drop between 2 grids

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to implement drag and drop between 2 grids but haven't found any information in the docs. I don't see any mention of it in the roadmap also.

Tried Googling for some info as well but it looks like the examples don't apply to Angular2.

Can anyone suggest an approach for this?

Comment: Hi @VladimirIliev, do you have an approach in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted the same question on GitHub, drag and drop is unavailable at this time.

Edit: Link to GitHub issue: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/56

Comment: Can you please share a link of issue from Github? It will be useful for others.